# Openlayers Rotate road name

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

On GeoServer, i get a layer group as base layer to show the map.
[base_osm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGrAb.png)

And a layer contains road names.I get this with Openlayers.
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW0By.png)

Now i want to rotate road name 180 degrees.
I try to find some solutions but get nothing(maybe in the wrong way)...
Would you give me some advice or a solution?
My English is not good,hope you get what i want to express.
**Thanks!!!**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function init() {
    var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

    var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(103.598434448242, 1.24977505207062,
            103.993843078613, 1.48103499412537);
    var options = {
        controls : [ new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({displayProjection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")}),],
        maxExtent : bounds,
        projection : proj,
        displayProjection : proj,
        units : 'degrees'
    };

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('ol-map', options);

    var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("test_osm",
            "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/osm/wms"
            , {
                LAYERS : 'osm:base_osm',
                STYLES : '',
                format : 'image/png',
                tiled : true,
            }, {
                buffer : 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent : true,
                isBaseLayer : true,

            });
    map.addLayer(tiled);

    var tiled2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("test_osm2",
            "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/osm/wms"
            , {
                LAYERS : "osm:highway-label",
                transparent: true,
                STYLES : '',
                format : "image/svg+xml",
                tiled : true,
                transparent : true,
            }, {
                buffer : 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent : true,
                isBaseLayer : false,
            }); 
    map.addLayer(tiled2); 
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

The above is my code that i get the map,i have no idea for the next step...

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: why do you want to do this? may http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#angle will help?

Comment: When map rotated (for example) 180 degrees,a horizontal road name will turn upside down.I want to make the road name In accordance with normal reading habits.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to find methods like `accordingLineString` for set text style. Only way I've found, calculate your `rotation` for street and set text style:

`text: new ol.style.Text({
    rotation: 0.3
    //your styles
  })`

[look this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138424/how-to-rotate-text-with-view-using-openlayers-3)

Comment: In that question,it seems that i need to define the style like the style on GeoServer for the highway-label(name of the road name layer) in js,and add the rotation ?

Comment: Yes, you should define the styles for feaure. google for examples or look at http://openlayers.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your labels are rendered server-side, so there's nothing you can do client side (using OpenLayers) to change the way labels are rendered.

You should edit the style (SLD) used by the osm:highway-label layer.

You can find good examples here
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html

but I think you are looking for label Rotation config, explained here
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#rotation